# Convert big int VBA

Tags: vbscript

Im having to edit code in very old classic asp.
Im comparing two values. 
I am getting an error saying `Type mismatch`

This is where it occurs:

```
if oRsDropDown(id_col) = variable then
```

the drop down is created form a sql execution

I think the issue may be that the ID column in the db being compared is a big int?

Comment: what is the type of [variable] ?  what are the contents of both sides of the comparison when the error appears ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the type that oRsDropDown returns, does it work with `is`?

```
if oRsDropDown(id_col) is variable then
```